# Visual Studio to load Qt source code for debugging

Tags: visual-studio, qt, debugging

I had compiled Qt 4.6.2 from sources with VS 2008. Now I would like to be able to step into Qt sources while debugging my application. How do I make VS to pick up the framework sources?

I forgot to mention that qt was built statically, and I don't find any .pdb files anywhere. I believe that all the necessary data should be included in the debug .lib files?

Comment: It should do so automatically, assuming you still have the source in the same place you compiled it.

Comment: Even if you have compiled a .lib in static, you need pdb to debug the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you compile the debug version of Qt ? To do so, you need to give -debug or -debug-and-release arguments to the configure step. I believe that even for static version, you will get pdb files.

Comment: I do have release and debug libs, but no .pdb files. I think Qt was configured with -debug-and-release, as it is the default option.

Comment: Did you compile it using nmake ?

Comment: well I actually used a clone of nmake called jom to employ all four cores of my machine: http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/03/27/speeding-up-visual-c-qt-builds/

Comment: I just tried to compile Qt on my computer:

configure -static -debug
and then 
nmake. And I get a lot of pdb files generated.

Comment: I remember that I also called `nmake clean` after compiling to get rid of the .obj files. It probably deleted .pdb files as well..

Answer (score 1):

From your question,

> I belive that all the necessary data
>   should be included in the debug .lib
>   files?

No need at all. There **should not** be any dlls or libs **associated with Qt** since you have the source files itself.

Say for example you want to step through `QWidget`.

So in the `cpp` file you will use like,

```
QWidget *trialWidget = new QWidget();
```

Now what you have to do is, you have to include the `header file` for `QWidget` (`qwidget.h` *I guess*) and the `cpp` file for `QWidget` (`qwidget.cpp` in that case).

Make note that, **all the other classes that might be needing** in the `qwidget.h` **should also be included**. Say for e.g `qobject.h` for `QObject`.

In this way you are **replacing the dlls and libs** with the **source code** itself, so that **you can step into** the `Qt` code available in the corresponding `cpp` files.

Hope it helps..

Comment: the .vcproj project file is generated by `qmake -tp vc` command, and it does not reference any framework sources, it will be quite painful to reference all the sources I need every time the project is regenerated... I think there should be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `.pdb` file for your Qt assembly is in your bin directory, alongside the `.dll`, and you should be able to step into the source.

Comment: Qt is built statically, there are no .pdb files, as there are no assemblies.

Comment: @ak. Note that .pdb files must be generated under -debug or -debug-and-release, but you should keep in mind that cleaning Qt dir by call to `nmake clean` deletes all .pdb files among other.